Wrong zoom on initial region when using react-native-map
I am using react-native-map package and I am not able to set initalRegion zoom.
This is how my component looks like:
const Map = ({ size }) => {
const [location, setLocation] = useState(null);
const [isExpanded, setIsExpanded] = useState(false);
const mapRef = useRef(null);

const windowHeight = Dimensions.get('window').height;
const windowWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width;

const smallHeight = windowHeight * 0.25;
const smallWidth = windowWidth * 0.9;

const animatedHeight = useRef(new Animated.Value(smallHeight)).current;
const animatedWidth = useRef(new Animated.Value(smallWidth)).current;

useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
        let { status } = await Location.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync();
        if (status !== 'granted') {
            return;
        }

        let location = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({});
        setLocation(location);
        if (mapRef.current && location) {
            mapRef.current.animateToRegion({
                latitude: location.coords.latitude,
                longitude: location.coords.longitude,
                latitudeDelta: 0.005,
                longitudeDelta: 0.005,
            }, 1000);
        }
    })();
}, []);

const handlePress = () => {
    setIsExpanded(true);

    Animated.timing(animatedHeight, {
        toValue: windowHeight,
        duration: 500,
        useNativeDriver: false,
    }).start();

    Animated.timing(animatedWidth, {
        toValue: windowWidth,
        duration: 500,
        useNativeDriver: false,
    }).start();
};

const handleClose = () => {
    setIsExpanded(false);

    Animated.timing(animatedHeight, {
        toValue: smallHeight,
        duration: 500,
        useNativeDriver: false,
    }).start();

    Animated.timing(animatedWidth, {
        toValue: smallWidth,
        duration: 500,
        useNativeDriver: false,
    }).start();
};

if (!location) {
    return (
        <View style={styles.loadingContainer}>
            <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#6C46FE" />
        </View>
    );
}

return (
    <>
        {isExpanded && (
            <Modal
                transparent={true}
                animationType="slide"
                visible={isExpanded}
                onRequestClose={handleClose}
            >
                <View style={styles.modalContainer}>
                    <MapView
                        ref={mapRef}
                        provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
                        customMapStyle={darkCustomStyle}
                        rotateEnabled={false}
                        pitchEnabled={isExpanded}
                        scrollEnabled={isExpanded}
                        zoomEnabled={isExpanded}
                        showsUserLocation
                        style={styles.fullScreenMap}
                        initialRegion={{
                            latitude: location.coords.latitude || 46.05,
                            longitude: location.coords.longitude || 14.51,
                            latitudeDelta: 0.005,
                            longitudeDelta: 0.005,
                        }}
                    />
                    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.closeButton} onPress={handleClose}>
                        <Text style={styles.closeButtonText}>Close</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
            </Modal>
        )}
        {!isExpanded && (
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={handlePress} style={styles.container}>
                <Animated.View style={{ height: animatedHeight, width: animatedWidth }}>
                    <MapView
                        ref={mapRef}
                        provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
                        customMapStyle={darkCustomStyle}
                        rotateEnabled={false}
                        scrollEnabled={false}
                        zoomEnabled={false}
                        showsUserLocation
                        style={styles.mapStyle}
                        initialRegion={{
                            latitude: location.coords.latitude || 46.05,
                            longitude: location.coords.longitude || 14.51,
                            latitudeDelta: 0.005,
                            longitudeDelta: 0.005,
                        }}
                    />
                </Animated.View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        )}
    </>
);
};

As you can see I properly set Deltas to closely zoom in but my simulator does not act appropriately. Below is the picture of the initial render of my map, and zoom is wrong.

When I click on the map I get the correct zoom.

And when I close it the small map zoom is also correct.

So my question is what am I doing wrong that on the first render, the deltas are not applied? I have already tried to apply zooom restrictions from react-native-map
Here is my package.json since it might be versions but I think the fault is in my useEffect somehow...
"dependencies": {
"@clerk/clerk-expo": "^2.2.5",
"@formatjs/intl-displaynames": "^6.6.8",
"@formatjs/intl-locale": "^4.0.0",
"@formatjs/intl-pluralrules": "^5.2.14",
"@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.23.1",
"@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.7.2",
"@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.18",
"axios": "^1.7.7",
"expo": "^51.0.31",
"expo-crypto": "^13.0.2",
"expo-file-system": "~17.0.1",
"expo-image-manipulator": "~12.0.5",
"expo-image-picker": "~15.0.7",
"expo-linking": "^6.3.1",
"expo-localization": "^15.0.3",
"expo-location": "^17.0.1",
"expo-router": "^3.5.23",
"expo-secure-store": "^13.0.2",
"expo-status-bar": "~1.12.1",
"expo-web-browser": "^13.0.3",
"form-data": "^4.0.0",
"i18next": "^23.15.0",
"lottie-react-native": "6.7.0",
"react": "18.2.0",
"react-dom": "18.2.0",
"react-i18next": "^15.0.1",
"react-native": "0.74.5",
"react-native-country-flag": "^2.0.2",
"react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.16.1",
"react-native-loading-spinner-overlay": "^3.0.1",
"react-native-maps": "1.14.0",
"react-native-reanimated": "^3.10.1",
"react-native-safe-area-context": "4.10.5",
"react-native-screens": "3.31.1",
"react-native-social-buttons": "^1.4.2"

}
